# Multiple peers connected

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, connectivity

I'm developing a game that requires up to four iPhones or iPod Touch to connect each other to play in turns.

My question is, how can I accomplish this via GameKit. I've read that using client/server sessions is the way of doing it. But I can't find any examples that would illustrate this.

Is it really possible to do it, or there can only be two devices connected at a time.

I'd really appreciate if you all could help me with a code sample.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is possible with the Gamekit framework.  Easiest method is to use bluetooth, which means short range (as in the same room).  I'm working on a similar application with the Gamekit framework.  Look at the sample code on developer.apple.com for GKTank and GKRocket.  These game demos are for two devices, but the framework will support what you need.  In a bluetooth piconet you can have eight devices connected.  Hope this helps you get started.